# focussing cursor in textbox using xaml in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

```
private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{           
    txt1_focus.Focus();
}
```

How can i achieve the above code using using xaml file in wpf.

Answer (score 2):

use the `FocusManager.FocusedElement`like below:

```
<Window x:Class="UI.Views.MyView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=txtSearch}">
    </Window>
```

Comment: the cursor should be focusing on textbox when text is changed in textbox.

Answer (score 1):

http://cloudstore.blogspot.com/2008/06/setting-initial-focus-in-wpf.html

This site explains how to set the initial focus on a certain control.

```
<Window ...
        FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=TextBox1}">
```